# Error: The hook `sails-seed` is taking too long to load

Tags: node.js, centos, sails.js

I have my node application in centOs machine, and I cant do `sails lift` because appears the next message:

[image]

My config file is:

[image]

Sorry about my english.

Comment: @MU done, it is my config folder structure

Comment: Assuming you are using `sails-seed` npm package, check your `seeds.js` content for any syntax error. In case there is lot of data you are seeding, increase the timeout from 40 seconds.